# how to reduce number of tick label in javafx categoryaxis

Tags: javafx

I'm drawing a line chart with javafx categoryaxis. e.g. I have 100 points on the plot. As such, all of my tick labels are squished together, resulting in 100 bunched-up ellipses. All I want to do is render every tenth label. I've looked through the documentation but there doesn't seem to be any way to turn individual tick labels visible or invisible, or how to change the setting of the tick unit on a CategoryAxis.
or I have to redraw xAxis?

Answer (score 4):

just got an idea, add number of invisible char into the categoryaxis, so that each xaxis is still 'unique'

```
    if (i%5 == 0)
        str = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT).format(date);
    else {
        str = invisible;
        invisible += (char)29;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. Accept your own answer! :-)

Comment: @jon I didn't quite get this, and it's my problem too. Could you clarify? Thanks!